# Leading space before a character in a string - count prefix space

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have  a string

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;-123
```

I need to get 2 as count.

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-12&&nbsp;3
```

I need to get 4 as count. (in which case i want 3 ie. spaces before '-').

The code i use is

```
stringValue.Count(countSpace => countSpace == ' ');
```

How do i pass a constraint check ie. "-" dash in this case and get the spaces before "-" dash and after "-".

Comment: Try rephrasing your question, It's not very clear what you are after.

Comment: Will we have to worry about there being multiple dashes?

Comment: Also, you want the number of spaces surrounding the dash, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are one or zero dashes, this will work:

```
public static int CountSurroundingSpaces(string stringValue, char constraint)
{
    return stringValue.SkipWhile( c => c != constraint)
                      .Skip(1)
                      .TakeWhile( c => c == ' ')
                      .Count() +
           stringValue.Reverse()
                      .SkipWhile( c => c != constraint)
                      .Skip(1)
                      .TakeWhile( c => c == ' ')
                      .Count();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use TrimStart() method to get the original string without trailing spaces and then count the difference between the lengths of the original and the trimmed one:

```
    stringValue.Length - stringValue.TrimStart().Length
```

**EDIT**

To count numbers of spaces in a string split by some separator, try this:

```
    static IEnumerable<int> GetSpaceCounts(string stringValue, char separator)
    {
        return stringValue.Split(separator).Select(s => s.Count(c => c == ' '));
    }
```

To test this code you may use:

```
    string stringValue = "    -123 12-  ";

    foreach (int i in GetSpaceCounts(stringValue, '-'))
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    Console.ReadLine();
```